# Micheal Hartl ch 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and am stuck on chapter 7 of the Michael Hartl tutorial. I have been geting this error after the first sign up in 7.4.3:

```
Missing partial shared/_error_messages with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have created the file mentioned in the error message?

Comment: When you write a question, you should assume that nobody reading it has a specific textbook to hand:  describe the problem in a standalone way.

Answer (score 3):

`Missing partial shared/_error_messages :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]`

- You have a `missing partial`.
- It should be in `shared/`
- It should be named `_error_messages`
- It should have a `.html` extension followed by one of `.erb, .builder, .raw, .ruby, .coffee, .jbuilder`

It's a pretty straightforward error message.